# ReplaceAll does not work on derivatives

Tags: replacement, calculus-and-analysis

```
(q''[x] - Exp[q[x]/2)] /. q[x] -> y[x] + a*t[x]
```

gives

```
-Exp^[1/2 (y[x] + a*t[x])] + q''[x]
```

Which is not what I want.

I would like to have

```
-Exp^[1/2 (y[x] + a*t[x])] + y''[x] + a*t''[x]
```

Is that possible?

Comment: Do this: `q -> (y[#] + a*t[#]&)`. (Duplicate, but I don't have time to look for it.)

Comment: Nice, the search engine didn't show me anything, but I am bad at formulating questions.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Check the [`FullForm`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/FullForm.html) of your expression.  That will make it clear why it doesn't work.

The solution is to replace `q` and not `q[x]`.

```
q''[x] - Exp[q[x]/2] /. q -> Function[x, y[x] + a*t[x]]
```

---

Recommended reading:

- [Everything is an expression](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/tutorial/ExpressionsOverview.html)
- [The representation of derivatives](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/tutorial/TheRepresentationOfDerivatives.html)
- [Pure functions](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/tutorial/PureFunctions.html)

Comment: I checked `FullForm` before posting and it showed me `Derivative[2][q][x]`, hence I assumed (without checking) that if I replace just `q` with a function of `x` I will get something like `(...[x])[x]` and so I didn't even try it

Comment: @user1482714 `q -> f[x]` of course won't work.  You need `q -> Function[x, f[x]]`.